# Internal server error

Tags: web-server, load-balancing, apache-2.2

I was trying to use the mod_proxy_balance module of apache to setup a loadbalancer for 2 webservers in the background. I thought I successfully did. Here's what happened:

1. My proxy is in abcd.edu. I enabled abcd.edu/test to be redirected to 2 webservers abc.edu/PHP and acb.edu/PHP.
2. Now if I enter abcd.edu/test in my address bar, I am able to reach those webservers. But I cannot access any page beyond it. eg If I enter abcd.edu/test/star.jpg . It says Internal server error. It is misconfigured. If I enter abc.edu/PHP/star.jpg , I am able to access it.

I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.search-computing.net/2010/04/load-balancing-with-apache-a-tutorial-on-mod_proxy_balancer-installation-and-configuration/comment-page-1/#comment-1499) to setup the mod_proxy_balance.

Can you please let me know what exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: Config files or it didn't happen.

Comment: In the client side, My program gives Connection Time out. The load balancer error logs give : do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: unable to send;errno = Operation not permitted

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of your httpd.conf configuration that contains your proxy directives?

Comment: <IfModule mod_proxy_balancer.c>

    <Proxy balancer://hgcc13.org>
        BalancerMember http://hgccvm90.org/ loadfactor=1
        BalancerMember http://hgccvm92.org/ loadfactor=1
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass      balancer://hgcc13.org/
    </Location>
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! I just disabled the firewall at the proxy !!